# Ansible: Is there a way of importing an entire tags list?

Tags: ansible, tags

Ansible: I want to know if there's a way of importing tags which is actually a list of all tasks I want to perform.
For example:

playbook1-

```
tasks:
  - name: copy and paste
    copy:
      src: /etc/file1
      dest: /etc/doc
    tags: 
     - task1
  - name: deleting
    file:
      path: /home/usr/Desktop/abc
      state: absent
    tags:
     - task2
  - name: creating a directory
    file:
      path: /home/usr/Downloads/abc
      state: directory
    tags:
      - task3
```

Now what I want is a common tags list which i can just import in the beginning of the same playbook so that while running I don't have to mention them in command line.
Somewhat like this:

playbook1-

```
- import_tags: tags.yml
  hosts: servers
  tasks:
  -
```

This tags.yml should contain the list  of tags or say the tasks I want to perform.

```
tags:
  - task1
  - task2
  - task3
```

Is there any way of **importing tags (import_tags:)** list like we do for importing playbooks (import_playbook:)?

Comment: Although, in first intention, the answer would be now, I feel like this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what are you really trying to achieve here? Maybe what you are looking could be, for example, achieved by includes, imports or roles.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I want to import the tags list, what if I've a list of 20 tasks, I can't keep on adding tags in command line neither I can set a common tag for all, it depends on the operation, if I want to run specific tasks, then I need different tags for all. It would have been simpler if I got to add the tags list at the beginning of the playbook which reads all the tags in one go just like a configuration file (where we can mention the tasks which need to be run in the specific execution).  So, I'm looking for something which can suffice my problem of running the set of tasks.

Comment: So it really looks to me that what you are searching for is to reorganise your playbook(s) into reusable [roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html).

Answer (score 0):

By default ansible runs as if "--tags all" has been specified . If you got a requirement to skip certain tags then you can utilize --skip-tags which I believe will narrow down your requirement.